# getPackageManager Non-Static Error

Tags: android

I want to check an app is Installed on user device or not my class is extends fragment so I have to use `Context.getPackageManager()` instead of `getPackageManager()` when I try I got a Non-static error what is a solution in this case?

here is my  function code:

```
private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
  PackageManager pm = Context.getPackageManager();

  try { 
    pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    return true;
  } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: at first pass Context `appInstalledOrNot` in this method

Comment: `private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri,Context ctx)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `getActivity().getPackageManager()`